# Can Jekyll omit index.html from folder URLs?

Tags: jekyll

The Jekyll [docs on creating pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) include this example of folders containing `index.html` files:

> To achieve clean URLs for pages using Jekyll, you simply need to create a folder for each top-level page you want, and then place an `index.html` file in each page’s folder. This way the page URL ends up being the folder name, and the web server will serve up the respective `index.html` file. Here’s an example of what this structure might look like:
>
> ```
> .
> ├── _config.yml
> ├── _includes/
> ├── _layouts/
> ├── _posts/
> ├── _site/
> ├── about/
> |   └── index.html  # => http://example.com/about/
> ├── contact/
> |   └── index.html  # => http://example.com/contact/
> |── other/
> |   └── index.md    # => http://example.com/other/
> └── index.html      # => http://example.com/
> ```

Note that the URLs in the example are just the folder names — no `index.html`.

When I use this structure in my own Jekyll site, though, a template like this:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}{% if page.title %}
    <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

…outputs HTML like this:

```
<a href="/projects/index.html">Projects</a>
<a href="/blog/index.html">Blog</a>
```

Someone suggested using front matter like this to fix the URLs:

```
---
permalink: projects/
---
```

This gives me the URLs I want but requires that I add that for each page. Is there a way to get Jekyll to omit `index.html` from the URL automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Jekyll 2.4.0, which GitHub Pages uses, but is fixed in Jekyll 3.