# Jekyll extension-less permalinks with markdown

Tags: jekyll

From the Jekyll [docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) it says (using `.md` format):

> Clean URLs can also be achieved using the `permalink` front matter variable. In the example above, using the first method, you can get URL `http://example.com/other` for the file `other.md` by setting this at the top of the file: `permalink: /other`

Here is an example my page front matter:

```
---
layout: page
title: Contact
permalink: /contact
---
```

Everything works fine when I'm using `jekyll serve` but when I `build` and upload to my static host it doesn't work. The file structure Jekyll outputs doesn't make sense for the functionality it claims from the docs.

```
.
|-- css/
|-- index.html    # => http://example.com/
└── contact.md    # => http://example.com/contact.html
```

I want to be able to go to `http://example.com/contact` and have it show `contact.md`. I know I could have similar functionality by manually putting my files in folders (and then renaming them all to `index.html`) like it says in the docs [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/#named-folders-containing-index-html-files), but I don't want to have to go through the extra step **and** I don't prefer the trailing `/` e.g. `http://example.com/other/`.

I am using `Jekyll 3.0.1`

---

I have found these questions but they don't address the problem I'm facing.

[How to link to a page with page.url without the html extension in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034994/how-to-link-to-a-page-without-html-extension-in-jekyll)

[How to make all posts have a permalink with custom format "domain.com/blog/title"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286964/jekyll-permalinks)

[Can Jekyll omit index.html from folder URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863745/can-jekyll-omit-index-html-from-folder-urls)

Comment: Have you tried this solution? having `permalinks: /:title` in the `_config.yml`, looks like a similar case as my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791004/jekyll-pretty-permalinks-give-me-webrick-error/31791757#31791757

If it works i'll post an answer :) I have my site set up similar to what you want, where a folder `contact` will be created in the folder, inside it is an `index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it correctly, it is just a matter of configuring your webserver properly (assuming it supports removing the extension). It works properly locally cause the built in jekyll webserver can do it by default. The docs have info on this here:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#extensionless-permalinks

On AWS S3 it says you can host with extensionless urls by uploading files with no extension at all, and then setting the content type to text/html. I don't think it is possible to get jekyll to output `contact.html` as just `contact` with no extension. So you get the web server to remove the extension, if it supports that (on s3 I use the trailing /).

This has some interesting info too:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3345

Comment: Yes, you're right about the webserver config. I guess there's the docs and the there's the docs... :) Good thread on Github too.

Answer (score 3):

I am also using clean permalink in my jekyll blog.

Here is my frontmatter:

```
---
layout: directory
title: About
permalink: about/
---
```

Got any different? , it is trailing slash at the end of URL. I know, you don't want to see any trailing slash at the end of URL, but for that you need to [use nginx](http://rickharrison.me/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-jekyll-urls-using-nginx), **because Jekyll generate all post/page like this /folder/index.html.**

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article about nginx, it was very insightful.